# Can the list of C++ files in a Visual Studio project be dynamically filled?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, compilation

I have a tool that generates most (but not all) files that need to be compiled in Visual Studio. The tool reads a configuration file and generates c++ files afterwards. This list can differ from one call to another when the configuration is altered.

I am wondering whether it would be possible to adapt the compiling process to my needs, which would be :

1. Launch the tool (not needed if configuration file has been modified)
2. Retrieve new list of C++ files to be compiled (ideally isolated in a folder inside the project)
3. Compile C++ files

EDIT: Having to close Visual Studio for this process to work is a no-go for me. The idea would be to have cpp files dynamically added as the first step of the compilation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a pre-build step to run your tool.

  - Also, create a file containing the list of includes and sources
  - This file name should be fixed (so that you don't have to change project properties or the  vcproj file) -- add it to the project. E.g:
    Project Properties > Command Line > Additional Options > @headerListingFile

You are not trying to integrate lex/yacc output with VS, are you?

Comment: No I am not. I'll look into what you're suggesting

Comment: The tool is in-house (i can change its behaviour if necessary)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should do is create a custom makefile and use that for builds.

Please [see this page for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: Does it mean i have to separate my project into two ?

Answer (score 1):

Would [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) help? It's an automated project manager that generates Makefiles and VS projects for projects you define. Just add a source file, re-run CMake and you're done.

Comment: I am afraid not. There is a part of the project (some c++ files) which i do not want to change... CMake cannot dynamically modify the project, it can only be run from outside Visual Studio... Nice tool, though.

Comment: I thought it might be useful because your tool could be modified to simply output a set() statement to a file, where your main CMakeLists.txt file could include() it. Then, when you run CMake, it spits out your updated project. It's only a little inconvenient to restart VS, IMO.