# Adding Existing Files To Project Externally Without Using VISUAL STUDIO 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

My issue is copying *.cs files to my project using my own code generator program (like hibernate)
So when my code generator program creates new .cs class I want it to be copied to project path and see it via VS2008 solution explorer.

(Note: Normally you can copy files to project folder but VS2008 doesn't see it since you didn't use VS2008 interface)

Thanks for your brilliant answers.

Comment: Looks dup: See <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591078/can-the-list-of-c-files-in-a-visual-studio-project-be-dynamically-filled/591239#591239> Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add files to the project, you'll have to parse and modify the C# project (.csproj) file.  You need to add tags for:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="MyNewFile.cs">
    <SubType>Code</SubType>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

See your existing .csproj file for more examples of files you can add.

Comment: Thanks it works. for those using VS2008. The syntax below is valid

<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="DB\DBAccessLevels.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

Answer (score 0):

If you bust open the .vcproj file in notepad, you'll see something like this:

```
<Files>
    <Filter
        Name="Source Files"
        Filter="cpp;c;cxx;def;odl;idl;hpj;bat;asm;asmx"
        UniqueIdentifier="{4FC737F1-C7A5-4376-A066-2A32D752A2FF}"
        >
        <File
            RelativePath=".\foo.cpp"
            >
        </File>
```

You need to use your favorite XML parsing API to add more  elements.

EDIT:

For a .csproj, add more elements like this:

```
<Compile Include="foo.cs" />
```